Can the LP tokens be burnt of a 'frozen' token?
If i were to add liquidty to a token but after some time the owner froze the token, will the burning of my LP tokens go through the network? I'm afraid it won't let me because i will receive both SOL and the token itself, maybe because its frozen it won't let me burn it.

You can't burn frozen tokens unfortunately. Frozen token accounts are completely unusable by the owner.
More info at https://spl.solana.com/token#freezing-accounts
